# Delphi zlib / iOS incompatibility?

Tags: ios, delphi, zlib

i have compressed some files with delphi using zlib from here
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Berlin/en/ZLibCompressDecompress_(Delphi)

### delphi code from link above

```
var
  LInput, LOutput: TFileStream;
  LZip: TZCompressionStream;

begin
  { Create the Input, Output, and Compressed streams. }
  LInput := TFileStream.Create(Edit1.Text, fmOpenRead);
  LOutput := TFileStream.Create(Edit2.Text + '.zip', fmCreate);
  LZip := TZCompressionStream.Create(LOutput, zcDefault);

  { Compress data. }
  LZip.CopyFrom(LInput, LInput.Size);

  { Free the streams. }
  LZip.Free;
  LInput.Free;
  LOutput.Free;
```

---

but when trying to decompress with xcode/ios, i get no errors but decompressed data is not same?

### xcode zlib

inp is input nsdata

```
  z_stream strm;
    strm.zalloc=Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree=Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque=Z_NULL;
    strm.total_out=0;
    strm.next_in=(Bytef *)[inp bytes];
    strm.avail_in=(uint)[inp length];
   if (deflateInit2(&strm, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED, (15+16), 8, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY) != Z_OK) return nil;

    NSMutableData *comp = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:16384];
    do
    {
        if (strm.total_out>= [comp length]){ [comp increaseLengthBy:16384];}
        strm.next_out=[comp mutableBytes] + strm.total_out;
         strm.avail_out=(uint)[comp length] - (uint)strm.total_out;
        deflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);

    } while (strm.avail_out==0);
    deflateEnd(&strm);
    [comp setLength:strm.total_out];
```

---

anyone have idea?

Comment: A complete [mcve] showing how you compress and how you decompress is needed. Otherwise this is just guesswork.

Comment: ok, sample code added

Answer (score 0):

well, after few days, then answer was pretty simple, i wanted to decompress file i compressed with delphi, so used wrong procedure ;-)
needed to use INFLATE instead of deflate(compress)